# 405 error for POST on Docker Container in Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I tested a container I built locally. It accepts a POST request with a file and returns another processed file.

I uploaded the container to Artifact Registry on GCP. I have been trying to make some POST requests from my computer to test the service. Here is a CURL below, same issue with various client libraries. The same request works when I use a local port instead of the cloud run URL.

```
curl --globoff https://SERVICE_NAME.a.run.app  
-X POST  
-H "content-type: application/json" 
-H "Authorization: bearer $(gcloud auth print-identity-token)"
-d '{"filename": RANDOM_FILE_NAME.pdf}'
```

I am receiving a 405 I pasted below.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 405</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /. Reason:
<pre>    HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</pre></p>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong ? I haven't seen any further options on Cloud Run I need to update, and I am clear my container accepts POST.

Comment: What"s the code that you deploy? in addition, did you try with a trailing /? Some framework like spring boot does not recognize the same URL with or without the trailing /

Comment: It is a ML pipeline which takes a PDF as an input and outputs a parsed JSON after processing.It communicates via FastApi. 

As for the trailing /, I tried to no avail - the 405 would imply the URL is recognised but the service just refuses to respond

Comment: Hi Matthieu, did you try my recommendation.Hope they were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The “HTTP ERROR 405” error occurs when the web server is configured in a way that does not allow you to perform a specific action for a particular URL.

It’s an HTTP response status code that indicates that the request method which uses PDF as an input and outputs a parsed JSON after processing is known by the server but is not supported by the target resource.

Also you need to make sure that the service account used by PubSub has proper IAM permissions so it can indeed trigger your app which is in reference to posting requests as per your requirement.
I would also suggest that you check this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/pubsub) which outlines step by step how to achieve this.